# Accounting profitability

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, accounting

Can anyone please help me how to solve this problem?

> Grocery Freshly want to open a new store. They expect an initial cost
>   of 30,000 to buy the property in which the store will be. After
>   opening, the annual cost of 10,000 is expected to generate 13,000 over
>   the next 10 years. Real estate will be depreciated by regular yearly
>   depreciation (after 10 years the whole property will be depreciated).
>   Does opening such a store looks like a good idea in terms of
>   accounting profitability, if the price of capital is 8% p.a., profit
>   tax 30% and we require at least 10% p.a. accounting profitability?
>   Consider continuous interest.

So I thought that the net accounting value is 0, since the whole property will be depreciated, average annual profit is 2100, since 13000-10000=3000, however without tax it is 2100 and Investment=30000

So my formula is:

ARR(Accounting rate of return)=$\frac{2100}{30000/2}=0.14$

Is that correct?

Comment: You haven’t included depreciation in your accounting profit calculation.

Comment: @dm63 yes, but I thought it is zero, can you explain me how to calculate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annual Accounting Profit = Revenues -costs - depreciation

Revenues =13000

Costs= 10000

Annual depreciation = 30000/10yrs = 3000

Therefore annual accounting profit =0

If you believe that the property market value will indeed depreciate like this, it doesn’t seem like a good investment.

Comment: Thank you, I think that was the key